# Errors Solving Elliptic PDES with FEM

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, solidmechanics

I am trying to solve the equation below governing transversely isotropic plane strain in cartesian coordinates with the given boundary conditions based on code found [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/compute-a-plane-strain-deformation.html) using Mathematica 10.1 on OSX El Capitan.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}\varepsilon_x\\\varepsilon_y\\\gamma_{xy}\end{bmatrix}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_x (x,y)\\u_y (x,y)\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_x\\\sigma_y\\\tau_{xy}\end{bmatrix}&=
\frac{1}{\left(1-v^2\right)}
\begin{bmatrix}
E&E v&0\\E v&E&0\\0&0&E\left(1-v\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\varepsilon_x\\\varepsilon_y\\\gamma_{xy}\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_x\\\sigma_y\\\tau_{xy}\end{bmatrix}&=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
Putting it all together to obtain the 2D Navier's equation (displacement formulation):
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-v^2\right)}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
0&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
E&E v&0\\E v&E&0\\0&0&E\left(1-v\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_x (x,y)\\u_y (x,y)\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Subject to the boundary conditions:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_x(0,-4.5)&=0.0\\
u_y(0,-4.5)&=0.0\\
u_x(0,4.5)&=0.0\\
u_y(0,4.5)&=0.2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
In the region $x^2+y^2=3.5^2$ subtracted from $x^2+y^2=4.5^2$.

I have written the following code to solve it but get a `NDSolve::dgsvars` error.

```
σ = {σx[x, y], σy[x, y], τxy[x, y]};
ε = {εx[x, y], εy[x, y], γxy[x, y]};
u={ux[x,y],uy[x,y]};

displacement2StrainOp[disp_?VectorQ]:=
Block[{x,y,null},
{Inactive[Div][{disp[[1]]},{x}],
 Inactive[Div][{disp[[2]]},{y}],
 Inactive[Div][{disp[[2]],disp[[1]]},{x,y}] 1/2}];

strain2StressOp[strain_?VectorQ,Ep_,v_]:=Block[
{multiplier=(1-v^2)^-1,
 matrix={{Ep,Ep v,0},{Ep v,Ep,0},{0,0,Ep(1-v)}}},
 multiplier matrix.strain];

stress2GovOp[stress_?VectorQ]:=Block[{x,y},
{Inactive[Div][{stress[[1]],stress[[3]]},{x,y}],
 Inactive[Div][{stress[[3]],stress[[2]]},{x,y}]}];

govEqns=
stress2GovOp[
strain2StressOp[
displacement2StrainOp[u],1.69 10^9,0.31]]//FullSimplify;

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

tRegion=ImplicitRegion[
((x - 0)^2 + (y - 0)^2 <= 4.5^2) && 
((x - 0)^2 + (y - 0)^2 >= 3.5^2),
{{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}];

tMesh=
ToElementMesh[tRegion, MaxCellMeasure->.25, "MeshOrder"->2];

fixedBC=
DirichletCondition[
{ux[x,y]==0., uy[x,y]==0.}, x==0 && y==-4.5];

prescribedDBC=
DirichletCondition[
{ux[x,y]==0., uy[x,y]==-0.2}, x==0 && y==4.5];

tE=1.69 10^9;
tv=0.31;

Show[
RegionPlot[tRegion, AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
tMesh["Wireframe"["ElementMeshDirective"->
Directive[Thick,EdgeForm[LightRed],FaceForm[Opacity[0.3],LightBlue]]]],
ListPlot[tMesh["Coordinates"],
{Axes->True, AspectRatio->1, 
PlotStyle->Directive[Red, PointSize[0.01]]}],
ImageSize->Large]

{tState}=NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
{govEqns=={0,0}, fixedBC, prescribedDBC},
{ux,uy},
{x, y} ∈ tMesh,
Method->"FiniteElement"]

NDSolve`Iterate[tState]

NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[tState]

uf = ux /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[tState]
vf = uy /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[tState]

dat = {Table[x, {x, {-4.5, 0, 4.5, 0}}], 
 Table[y, {y, {0, -4.5, 0, 4.5}}]} // Transpose
inf = Map[{uf[#[[1]], #[[2]]], vf[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, dat]
Show[Graphics[{Directive[LightRed, Thick], Circle[{0, 0}, 4.5]}], 
 ListPlot[{dat, dat + inf}, AspectRatio -> 1]]

tProbMesh = uf["ElementMesh"]
tDeformedProbMesh = ElementMeshDeformation[uMesh, {uf, vf}]
tDeformedProbMeshx5 = 
 ElementMeshDeformation[uMesh, {uf, vf}, "ScalingFactor" -> 5]

Show[
tProbMesh[
"Wireframe"[
"ElementMeshDirective" -> 
 Directive[Thin, EdgeForm[LightGreen], FaceForm[]]]], 
tDeformedProbMeshx5[
"Wireframe"[
"ElementMeshDirective" -> 
 Directive[Thick, EdgeForm[LightRed], 
 FaceForm[Opacity[0.3], LightBlue]]]]]
```

But then I get the error message `NDSolve::dgsvars: "The differentiation variables {x} given for Inactive[Div] should be the spatial independent variables {x,y}."` and the equation is not solved.

Modifying the code with changes to the functions below and reevaluating gives a different error message: `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations::femper: -- Message text not found -- (Div[{6.45038*10^8 Div$7030,5.796*10^8 ux$7029+1.86968*10^9 uy$7028}]) ``.

```
displacement2StrainOp[disp_?VectorQ]:=
Block[{x,y,null},
{Inactive[D][disp[[1]],x],
 Inactive[D][disp[[2]],y],
 Inactive[Div][{disp[[2]],disp[[1]]},{x,y}] 1/2}];
```

I do not know what else to try and will appreciate help on this issue. Am I missing something fundamental? I am open to other approaches to solve the problem as long as it uses FEM.

The reason for defining the problem this way is that I plan to later introduce a Young's modulus functionally dependent on x and y so I need a way to differentiate whatever expression passed in.

Thank you.

**Edit 1:**

As per the comment below (thanks), there is a zero traction condition at `x^2 + y^2 == 3.5^2`. I added it with

```
zeroTractionBC=NeumannValue[0,x^2 + y^2 == 3.5^2];
```

and then in the solver:

```
{tState}=NDSolveProcessEquations[{
  govEqns=={ zeroTractionBC, zeroTractionBC }, fixedBC, prescribedDBC},    
  {ux,uy}, 
  {x,y}\[Element]tMesh, Method->"FiniteElement"]
```

but still have the same error:

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations::temper:
-- Message text not found -- (Div[{6.45038*10^8 Div$17301,5.796*10^8 ux$17300+1.86968*10^9 uy$17299}])
```

**Edit 2:**
Based on issues from the post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80274/kernel-quits-without-error-in-ndsolvevalue) I have tried the same code on Mathematica 10.3 running on Windows 10 but I get the same set of errors. Please I will appreciate any help at this point.

Comment: Boundary conditions need to be applied at `x^2 + y^2 ==4.5^2` and `x^2 + y^2 == 3.5^2`.

Comment: Also, the alternative (second) representation of displacement2StrainOp seems preferable, although you may not need to use `Inactive`.  It also may not be necessary to use the components of `NDSolve` instead of `NDSolve` itself.  If so, this could save you much work.

Comment: @bbgodfrey you're right. There is a zero traction condition at `x^2 + y^2 == 3.5^2`. I added it with `zeroTractionBC=NeumannValue[0,x^2 + y^2 == 3.5^2];` and then in the solver: `{tState}=NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{govEqns=={zeroTractionBC,zeroTractionBC}, fixedBC, prescribedDBC},{ux,uy}, {x,y}\[Element]tMesh, Method->"FiniteElement"]` but still have the same error. Sorry for the delay; timezone differences and the comment box ate the backslash before `Element`.

Comment: Are you saying, then, that a zero-traction condition is to be applied everywhere on the interior and exterior boundaries except at the points `{0, 4.5}` and `{0, -4.5}`, where values are specified for `ux` and `uy`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes! But I do not know how to combine Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: Combining the two can be accomplished; see the `NeumannValue` documentation.  However, Mathematica will not handle `DirichletCondition` at single points.  So, over how wide an angle do you wish to apply the two Dirichlet boundary conditions?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Mathematica will handle `DirichletConditions` at single points, some care needs to be taken, however, that this point is part of the mesh as that is not detected automatically in all cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it. First, let's write a function that generates the plane stress PDE:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
ClearAll[PlaneStress];
PlaneStress[{Y_, nu_}, {u_, v_}, X : {x_, y_}] := 
 Module[{pStress}, 
  pStress = -Y/(1 - 
       nu^2)*{{{{1, 0}, {0, (1 - nu)/2}}, {{0, nu}, {(1 - nu)/2, 
        0}}}, {{{0, (1 - nu)/2}, {nu, 0}}, {{(1 - nu)/2, 0}, {0, 1}}}};

  {Inactive[Div][pStress[[1, 1]].Inactive[Grad][u, X], X] + 
    Inactive[Div][pStress[[1, 2]].Inactive[Grad][v, X], X], 
   Inactive[Div][pStress[[2, 1]].Inactive[Grad][u, X], X] + 
    Inactive[Div][pStress[[2, 2]].Inactive[Grad][v, X], X]}]
```

Now, you'd be able to call:

```
tE = 1.69 10^9;
tv = 0.31;
eqn = PlaneStress[{tE, tv}, {ux[x, y], uy[x, y]}, {x, y}] == {0, 0};
```

With the region and the boundary conditions:

```
tRegion=ImplicitRegion[((x-0)^2+(y-0)^2<=4.5^2)&&((x-0)^2+(y-0)^2>=3.5^2),{{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}}];
fixedBC=DirichletCondition[{ux[x,y]==0.,uy[x,y]==0.},x==0.&&y==-4.5];
prescribedDBC=DirichletCondition[{ux[x,y]==0.,uy[x,y]==-0.2},x==0.&&y==4.5];
{uxfun,uyfun}=NDSolveValue[{eqn,fixedBC,prescribedDBC},{ux,uy},{x,y} ∈ tRegion];
```

Visualizing:

```
mesh = uxfun["ElementMesh"];
Show[{
  mesh["Wireframe"[ "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]],
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uxfun, uyfun} ][
   "Wireframe"[
    "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

This looks reasonable. Adding a material dependency is then doing something like:

```
eqn = PlaneStress[{tE*x, tv}, {ux[x, y], uy[x, y]}, {x, y}] == {0, 0}
```

I just chose `tE*x` but you can go wild here, as long as it's linear it's fine.

**Update:**

Derivation of the PlaneStress operator. We start from the stress strain relation and replace the derivatives ex, ey and gxy with the actual definitions to give sx, sy and txy:

```
{sx, sy, txy} = Y/(1 - \[Nu]^2) ( {{1, \[Nu], 0},{\[Nu], 1, 0},{0, 0, (1 - \[Nu])/2}}).({{ex},{ey},{gxy}}) /. {ex -> D[u[x, y], x], ey -> D[v[x, y],y],gxy -> (D[u[x, y], y] + D[v[x, y], x])}

(* {{(Y*(\[Nu]*Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y]))/(1 - \[Nu]^2)}, 
 {(Y*(Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] + \[Nu]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y]))/(1 - \[Nu]^2)}, 
 {(Y*(1 - \[Nu])*(Derivative[0, 1][u][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][v][x, y]))/(2*(1 - \[Nu]^2))}} *)
```

Now, take the derivatives of sx, sy and txy:

```
{{-D[sx, x] - D[txy, y]},{-D[txy, x] - D[sy, y]}} // MatrixForm
```

This will give you the plane stress.

Comment: Nice analysis, which looks quite credible (+1).  However, I cannot reproduce the equations given in LaTex format at the top of the question from your `Activate[eqn]`.  Is the question in error, or have I missed something?  By the way, thanks for your earlier comment.

Comment: You may wish to add `<< NDSolve``FEM` (backquotes do not reproduce well here) to the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks for the for `[\Element]` fix and yes, a `<<NDSolve\`FEM\`` is needed. I'll look at your other question later, I need to attend to something else first.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I got similar results by simplifying both [mine](http://i.imgur.com/iVSOh4f.png?1) and [user21's](http://i.imgur.com/fBe1I5k.png) with the only difference being a multiplication by -1; also, I don't mind applying the Dirichlet conditions over an angle of say 5 degrees if you can show me how. user21, pardon my lack of mathematical prowess,  but is that a fourth order tensor you used? Thank you guys; I wish I could buy you all beers!

Comment: @user21 though I've established that in the end the results are similar, I would very much appreciate an explanation of how you arrived at the construct you have so I could apply the same to other equations I might have. Also, does using `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve` have any effect? Thanks in advance.